# How to prove that a given complex number of modulus 1 is not a root of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

How to prove that the complex number $\frac{1+\sqrt{15}i}{4}$ of absolute value $1$ is not a root of unity of any order? Just in case, this number is a root of the polynomial $2x^2 - x +2$.

Comment: Have you worked out the rational polynomial that this number satisfies?  Your post is pretty terse.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, the polynomial is $2x^2-x+2$

Comment: This may help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68176/42969

Comment: For that to happen $\,p(x)=x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1\,$ would have to be a factor of $x^n-1$ for some $n$. But [Monic Factors in $\mathbb Q[x]$ of a Monic $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$ are also in $\mathbb Z[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505247/monic-factors-in-mathbb-qx-of-a-monic-f-in-mathbb-zx-are-also-in-ma) while $p(x)$ is obviously not.

Comment: It's an interesting kind of problem, but I imagine there is some context for it that could be shared to improve your Question.  E.g. where did this problem arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, consider $\alpha=1+\sqrt{-15}$.  We will argue that the imaginary part of $\alpha^n$ is never $0$ (for $n≥1$).  Clearly, that will suffice.  We remark that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^2-2x+16$

If we define $$\alpha^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt {-15}$$

with $a_n, b_n\in \mathbb Z$, we must have $$b_n=2b_{n-1}-16b_{n-2}$$

with $b_1=1, b_2=2$.

A routine induction tells us that the order of $2$ in $b_n$ increases by exactly $1$ as $n$ increases by $1$, hence $b_n$ never vanishes, and we are done.